# Wso2 identity server connection configuration with Microsoft active directory

Tags: active-directory, wso2

Following error is received at wso2 identity server console while connection to Microsoft Active Directory

> Error obtaining connection. [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580]
>   javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580]

where following user-mgt.xml configuration is

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
   <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
   <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://10.10.4.145:389</Property>
   <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=wso2admin,ou=Users</Property>
   <Property name="ConnectionPassword">root.123</Property>
   <Property name="AnonymousBind">false</Property>
   <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=prc,dc=com</Property>
   <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">identityPerson</Property>
   <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
   <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
   <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
   <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute" />
   <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
   <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
   <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=prc,dc=com</Property>
   <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
   <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
   <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
   <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
   <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
   <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
   <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
   <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
   <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
   <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
   <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
   <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
   <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
   <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
   <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
   <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
   <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
   <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
   <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
   <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
   <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
   <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
   <Property name="defaultRealmName">prc.com</Property>
   <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
   <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
   <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
   <Property name="ReadTimeout" />
   <Property name="RetryAttempts" />
</UserStoreManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

"error code 49" indicates bad credentials (the credentials you are using to try to connect).

I assume that's this:

```
<Property name="ConnectionName">uid=wso2admin,ou=Users</Property>
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Default+LDAP+User+Store+Configuration), this property should be "the DN (Distinguish Name) of the admin user in LDAP". But your distinguished name is incorrect for two reasons:

1. You cannot use `uid` in a distinguished name (the example uses `uid`, but that doesn't work with Active Directory). It should start with `CN=`.
2. You're missing the domain part of the DN, like "dc=prc,dc=com" (I'm assuming that's what it is for your domain"

So it should look something more like this (but you will have to verify it is correct):

```
<Property name="ConnectionName">cn=wso2admin,ou=Users,dc=prc,dc=com</Property>
```

Comment: after editing above parameters i got following error while adding user. Error while enabling the user account. Please check password policy at DC for user : root1

Comment: Sounds like this error is fixed then. If you need help with the new error, then you would be better off starting a new question and show your code.